# Vue reads all the properties of an object when using it (and triggers all the getters)

Tags: vue.js

I am seeing some unexpected behavior when including an external object as data into a component in VueJs 2.0.  Apparently, Vue will automatically read the properties of the object, triggering all their `getters`, when setting it as data in a component.

See comments in the `mounted()` function below.

```
import { web3 } from './web3/web3-load.js'

Vue.component('home', {
  data () {
    return {
      web3: null
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    console.log(web3) // this dont call any method of the web3 object
    this.web3 = web3  // this reads the properties of web3 and triggers their getter methods      }
})
```

`web3` is actually an instance of [Web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3js-api-reference), and is rather complex, it has several sub-elements and subfunctions.

**My question is:** Under which condition is it expected the Vue will automatically read all the properties of an object in the back when storing the object inside the framework? And, can this be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental nature of Vue is to convert objects added to data into *reactive* objects. As soon as you add an object to data, Vue will convert all of it's properties into observed properties. There isn't a way to turn this off.

If you want to avoid that behavior, you will need to create your own work around. Possibly use a method to return the `web3` object whenever you need it.

```
methods:{
  web3(){ return web3 }
}
```

That object will not be reactive, but you would have to use it as if it were a method (`this.web3().someWeb3Prop`).